# Pixela does not let me create graph (HTTP Error: 400) - user does not exist or the token is wrong

Tags: python, http, error-handling, coding-style

I get an error message (HTTP Error) 400 when trying to create a graph.
The user has been successfully generated, as can be seen from the below message:

```py
import requests

USERNAME = "testusermichael"
TOKEN = "2ködfajfölN!!"
GRAPH_ID = "graph1"

pixela_endpoint = "https://pixe.la/v1/users"

user_params = {
    "token": TOKEN,
    "username": USERNAME,
    "agreeTermsOfService": "yes",
    "notMinor": "yes",
}

graph_endpoint = f"{pixela_endpoint}/{USERNAME}/graphs"

graph_config = {
    "id": GRAPH_ID,
    "name": "Walking Graph",
    "unit": "Km",
    "type": "float",
    "color": "shibafu"
}

headers = {
    "X-USER-TOKEN": TOKEN
}

response = requests.post(url=graph_endpoint, json=graph_config, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

response from trying to create the user again:

```json
{
    "message": "This user already exist.",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

response from trying to create a graphic

```json
{
    "message": "User testusermichael does not exist or the token is wrong.",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

Comment: The response received is: {"message":"User `testusermichael` does not exist or the token is wrong.","isSuccess":false}

Comment: I think the API might have issues with the token you're using. I'm going to do something which I would normally not suggest to do, but try with a new user, and a new token. The token should be a simpler alphanumeric one. Looking at the docs, it can be up to 128 characters, but the docs are not clear on the character requirements.  Use something like [this site](https://www.gigacalculator.com/randomizers/random-alphanumeric-generator.php) to create a nice long random alphanumeric string

Comment: You are right. I have changed the Token to a simpler version with 5 numbers followed by 5 random letters - and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment discussion, it seems the API doesn't like some characters in the token. This might be due to character encoding, or the simple fact that it doesn't really accept non-alphanumeric tokens.

Fix is quite simple, which is to use a simple alphanumeric token. Since the length can be up to 128.

Use something like [this site](https://www.gigacalculator.com/randomizers/random-alphanumeric-generator.php) to generate a long token and use that to authenticate the other requests